# How do I create a nested list (matrix) with only the diagonals filled in?

Tags: python

This is a matrix filling program. How do I fill in only the diagonals and make the other elements all zeros?

Desired Output

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 16, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 25]]
```

Current Output (wrapped for readability)

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
 [9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
 [16, 16, 16, 16, 16]]
```

```
multiarray = []
for i in range(5):
    multiarray.append([])
    for j in range(5):
        multiarray[i].append(i**2)
print(multiarray)
```

Comment: You can use a conditional to either append `0` or `(i+1)**2`. You should be able to work out the details on your own.

Comment: if with numpy, ```a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).T
b = np.eye(5)
print(a ** 2 * b)``` , not an answer use `for`.

Comment: I've overhauled your question and I hope you'll agree it's clearer :) For the reasoning behind some of the changes, see [ask]. It's also worth reading that for the sake of future questions :) If anything's not to your liking, you can [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only one loop, as they is only one specific value to set, and its position is given by `i`, also you want the power of `i+1` not `i`

```
size = 5
multiarray = []
for i in range(size):
    multiarray.append([0] * size)
    multiarray[i][i] = (i + 1) ** 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(5):
    multiarray.append([0]*5)
    multiarray[i][i] = (i+1)**2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
multiarray = [[i**2*(i==j) for i in range(1,6)] for j in range(1,6)]
print(multiarray)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 16, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 25]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is `multiarray[i].append(i**2)`. What this does is append `i**2` to a list `j` times. In other words, you're filling an empty list with `i**2` repeated `j` times.

Here's an alternative solution since others have already covered the other approaches sufficiently:

```py
In [1]: n = 5

In [2]: [[0]*i + [(i + 1)**2] + [0]*(n - i - 1) for i in range(n)]
Out[2]:
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 9, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 16, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 25]]
```

To explain, I'm using the list repetition operator `*` and the list concatenation operator `+` to left- and right-pad each row a specific number of zeros. Here's what each 'term' of that expression looks like before concatenation:

```py
In [3]: for i in range(n):
   ...:     print([0]*i, [(i + 1)**2], [0]*(n - i - 1))
   ...:
[] [1] [0, 0, 0, 0]
[0] [4] [0, 0, 0]
[0, 0] [9] [0, 0]
[0, 0, 0] [16] [0]
[0, 0, 0, 0] [25] []
```